# how do i run 2 different codes from a button with addEventListener 'click' to work as an on/off functionality in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I have a 'click' event that turns the background of a page black, I need it to turn white after the same button is clicked again....

```
const lightButton = document.getElementById('sleep');

lightButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Screen.style.background = 'black';
```

how do I add this code so the screen turns white after the button is clicked again?

```
Screen.style.background = 'white';
```

Comment: You can use closure or a global variable which toggles its value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList toggle

Answer (score 1):

```
LightButton.addEventListener('click', () => {    
  if (Screen.style.background = 'black') {
    Screen.style.background = 'white';
  } else {
    Screen.style.background = 'black';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please lookup `ternary` or better: classList.toggle

Answer (score 0):

const screen = document.getElementById('screen');
const lightButton = document.getElementById('sleep');

```
lightButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (screen.style.backgroundColor == 'black') {
        screen.style.backgroundColor = null;
    } else {
        screen.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks guys I looked up classList.toggle that then led to me getting my answer, the light now turn on and off with using one button